# How can you compute a shortest addition chain for an arbitrary n <= 600 within one second?

Tags: performance, algorithm, numbers

How can you compute a [shortest addition chain (sac)](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/addition_chain.html) for an arbitrary n <= 600 within one second?

#### Notes

This is the programming competition on [codility](http://codility.com/) for this month.

Addition chains are numerically very important, since they are the most economical way to compute x^n (by consecutive multiplications).

Knuth's [Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2, Seminumerical Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201038226) has a nice introduction to addition chains and some interesting properties, but I didn't find anything that enabled me to fulfill the strict performance requirements.

#### What I've tried (spoiler alert)

Firstly, I constructed a (highly branching) **tree** (with the start 1->  2 -> ( 3 -> ..., 4 -> ...)) such that for each node n, the path from the root to n is a sac for n. But for values >400, the runtime is about the same as for making a coffee.

Then I used that program to find **[some useful properties for reducing the search space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131277/properties-of-shortest-addition-chains-for-small-numbers-e-g-up-to-600)**. With that, I'm able to build all solutions up to 600 while making a coffee. But for n, I need to compute all solutions up to n. Unfortunately, codility measures the class initialization's runtime, too...

Since the problem is [probably NP-hard](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109904/is-finding-the-length-of-the-shortest-addition-chain-for-a-number-n-really-np), I ended up **hard-coding a lookup table**. But since codility asked to **construct** the sac, I don't know if they had a lookup table in mind, so I feel dirty and like a cheater. Hence this question.

#### Update

**If you think a hard-coded, full lookup table is the way to go, can you give an argument why you think a full computation/partly computed solutions/heuristics won't work?**

Comment: Are you explicitly asked not to build a lookup table ? It is a valid solution to a problem.

Comment: I would also opt for a lookup. More like _ruse de guerre_ than a dirty cheater...

Comment: Ok, then problem's solved ;) Although I find codility's wording misleading - I'm not constructing a sac, I'm merely looking it up...

Comment: The one-second limit is absurdly high just to look up into a table with 600 entries. Either you're missing something, or they are ;-)

Comment: A hard-coded lookup table seems a bit .. cheap.

Comment: @harold & Steve: I think so, too. So any suggestions?

Comment: I still got nothing. Maybe it has to be done that way after all..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just got my Golden Certificate for this problem. I will not provide a full solution because the problem is still available on the site.I will instead give you some hints:

1. You might consider doing a deep-first search.
2. There exists a minimal star-chain for each n < 12509
3. You need to know how prune your search space.
4. You need a good lower bound for the length of the chain you are looking for.
5. Remember that you need just one solution, not all.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, slvr (+1). I used much stronger properties than star-chain - did you follow my link to math.stackexchange? I did use dynamic programming, though, and thought a DFS would not be able to find a solution quickly because there are relatively few SHORTEST addition chains. So now I know I did cheat for my Golden Certificate and have a nice task for my Sunday morning :)

Comment: I did read what you wrote on math.stackechange.com. Dynamic-programming, uh? Interesting. With DFS the upper bound for the running time was 80ms on a i5-2400.

Answer (score 2):

> Addition chains are numerically very important, since they are the
>   most economical way to compute x^n (by consecutive multiplications).

This is not true. They are not always the most economical way to compute x^n. Graham et. all  [proved](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/78_11_addition_chains.pdf) that:

> If each step in addition chain is assigned a cost equal to the product
>   of the numbers at that step, "binary" addition chains are shown to
>   minimize the cost.

Situation changes dramatically when we compute x^n (mod m), which is a common case, for example in cryptography.

Now, to answer your question. Apart from hard-coding a table with answers, you could try a Brauer chain.

A Brauer chain (aka star-chain) is an addition chain where each new element is formed as the sum of the *previous* element and some element (possibly the same). Brauer chain is a sac for n < 12509. Quoting [Daniel. J. Bernstein](http://cr.yp.to/papers/pippenger.pdf):

> Brauer's algorithm is often called "the left-to-right 2^k-ary method",
>   or simply "2^k-ary method". It is extremely popular. It is easy to
>   implement; constructing the chain for n is a simple matter of
>   inspecting the bits of n. It does not require much storage.

BTW. Does anybody know a decent C/C++ implementation of Brauer's chain computation? I'm working partially on a comparison of exponentiation times using binary and Brauer's chains for both cases: x^n and x^n (mod m).