# Addition Chains

Tags: java, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you compute a shortest addition chain for an arbitrary n <= 600 within one second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140052/how-can-you-compute-a-shortest-addition-chain-for-an-arbitrary-n-600-within-o)

What's the best way to code a program that computes the shortest addition chain for a number <= 500? I have tried depth first search with iterative deepening but it gets really slow for the larger values.

What other techniques could I use to cut the runtime significantly? Also, how should I prune the search space? Thanks!

Comment: I dont see really see how you would shorten the search space, if you have a tree that represents all possible addition paths from `1..N` you would need to potentially consider all of those paths when deciding what the `shortest` path is. Maybe you could post your DFS code ?